# How can I get all products in home page in open cart?

Tags: opencart2.x

I need to show all the products in home page in open cart. Any direct coding for this? which I can implement in home.tpl file & looping through & get the products.

Another thing is...the more sophisticated way...to create a new module itself which I can enable & assign in system->design->layout (in home layout)

Can anyone please help with this? I searched many but not clear instruction on how to do this. And no any information on how to copy any module & create our new one....because I am thinking to copy a latest module & get it working on my way :)

My Opencart version is 2.0.2.0

Comment: Ok I just got an new video tutorial so following it :- http://opencart.hostjars.com/blog/58

Comment: Enable the latest module and set limit to max number..
It will do the job

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Thanks for your reply :) Actually the thing was I were already using latest products in home page by that module :) & I were having requirement to show all products in another tab. So thought I should create a copy of latest module & use that as separate module :) & figure it out how to do it....by checking several videos & I wrote the answer :)

Comment: Here is extension will help you - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3889

Comment: Thank you monika :)

Yes this one is really useful :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer for creating module or say duplicating module.
I am duplicating Latest Module & please note my version is 2.0.2.0

Go to Admin folder in your root & copy latest.php & paste & rename to your module name from both :- controllers/module folder & in language folder & in that english/module folder.

Then copy latest.tpl & paste & rename to your module name in admin/view/template/module folder

& follow the same procedure in catalog folder in that controller, model & view folder.

Now whichever files you opened from above all folders in those all files replace latest to you module name.

Be sure you keep an eye on Class name where Latest comes there you need to write Your modules name...I mean first letter capital.

Good Luck :)